# How to add padding to the sides of an input based on the width of an absolute div in it?

Tags: css, sass

I'am in an Angular Project and i can use SASS. I have an input inside a wrap that contain the input and an icon like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <input type="text"/>
    <div class="wrapper-icons">
        <i class="icon">
    </div>
</div>
```

The wrapper-icons is absolute and positioned above the input at the right. I put on the input a right padding so when write inside the text don't overlap the icons.

I want to add multiple icon so the padding in the input should increase along with the width of the wrapper-icons.

here I add a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/alessandroinfo/pen/NWKBmVv) to clarify the problem.

How i can achieve this?

Comment: @piyush jain you removed the angular tag don't you thing angular can help here getting the dyanmic width of div I understand there can be css only ans but removing angular tag doesn't make sense here

Comment: @jitender1 there is no angular code in problem,  and issue is not related to angular , it is related to css.

Comment: @piyushjain i know but i solved a lots of problem like this using angular.Idea is set the padding style atrribute equal to width of dyanmic div and that is totally duable with angular

Comment: @jitender1 there are other ways also i can solve this problem, tags are for whether this problem is related to that particular tag or not.

Comment: You need to 'know' the number of icons and use that in the calculation of the width. You can do that in multiple ways. It all depends how the icons are being added. You add them manually ? or are they added in a for loop ? or other ways,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not absolutely want to put your icons inside the input you can follow this:

```
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
}

input {
  flex: 1;
  border: none;
}
```

`flex: 1` forces the input to grow and fill the rest of the space not used by the icons

Comment: The wrapper-icons div must go above input. So i need to put it absolute.

Comment: above how ? can you show us your code ? or add a minimal reproducing exemple

Comment: _“The wrapper-icons div must go above input.”_ - no, they don’t. That is what is causing the problem you are trying to fix here in the first place. You want the input to stretch as far as possible next to the icons, to avoid that problem, that you don’t know how much padding you need to specify. If you need a border to go around the icons as well or something like that - then apply it the parent element.

Comment: I see clearly now, you want absolutely that the icons must be above the input (visually inside the input) ?

Comment: i just modified my response, its the same as @04FS

Comment: @04FS the behaviour is what i want, but i need the behaviour of the input behind the icons. If i change the background color when focus the background color of icons will remain white.

Comment: Well then you are  really going to need a solution that counts how many icons you put in there and /or calculates what their combined width is, so that you can set the padding to that specific value.